# Android navigation: how could I pass entire route (not only final point) to external navigator software?

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, yandex-maps

my Android application generates route for user and updates it based on some other users actions/external events.
We talking not about "destination points" (visit here, here and here), but also full route (drive strictly this way).
What external navigation software on Android supports this mode? Could I pass full route to Google Maps / Yandex Navigator / Map.Me / OsmAND+ or some other navigator and have it use it instead of their route?